# Grant on multiple databases. MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant

How to grant on multiple databases? MySQL.

Something like

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE
ON 'databasesprefix%'.*
TO testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'testpasswd';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your example should work. from the [(5.5) manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html):

> The “_” and “%” wildcards are allowed when specifying database names in GRANT statements that grant privileges at the global or database levels.

with `%` matching any number (even zero) of characters, and `_` matching exactly one character. if you want a `_` in your database name, you have to escape it as `\_`. also watch the other caveats from the manual.

<**UPDATE**>as the other answer points out: if the database name contains wildcards, it has to be quoted with the [identifier quote character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html), the backtick (“`”)</**UPDATE**>

Answer (score 22):

You just need to use backticks instead of quotes around the db_name prefix.

I think this will work:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE
ON `databasesprefix%`.*
TO testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'testpasswd';
```

Comment: "You can't use wildcards in the db_name of a grant statement."

Yes you can.