# MySQL Grant for more than one database

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I'm trying to set the privileges for two databases at once. I know it is possible to assign them in two statements. Is there a way to do it in one?

I tried

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
       ON mydb1.*, mydb2.*
       TO 'reader'@'localhost'
       IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

But it only seems to work for one database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, as you can see in the [GRANT syntax diagram](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html). Although apparently, you can use the wildcard `*.*` to apply the grant to all databases, but I wouldn't do that.

Comment: That is not correct. It is true you cannot list more than one DB at a time, but you can use wildcards to grant on multiple databases at a time. See my answer here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036705/1593026

Answer (score 3):

From the GRANT documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html):

> The `_` and `%` wildcards are permitted when specifying database names in `GRANT` statements that grant privileges at the database level. This means, for example, that if you want to use a `_` character as part of a database name, you should specify it as `\_` in the `GRANT` statement, to prevent the user from being able to access additional databases matching the wildcard pattern; for example, GRANT ... ON `` `foo\_bar\`.*  TO .... ``

So, in order to do the above (mydb1 and mydb2), just do

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb%`.* TO 'reader'@'localhost';
```

Etc.  (Assuming you don't have a mydb3 or mydb_funkytown, etc., that you also don't want to grant privileges on.)

See also:

- [Grant on multiple databases. MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204188/grant-on-multiple-databases-mysql)
- [grant to multiple db using one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018331/grant-to-multiple-db-using-one-command)

Answer (score 0):

You can either grant privileges to all databases (using `*.*`) or one at a time, but not to 2 at one time.