# grant to multiple db using one command

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-administration, sql-grant

I have many `mariaDB` databases that has same prefix. Such as

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
....
apple5000
apple5001
banana1
banana2
...
banana100
```

And I want create new user `USER` who can `SELECT` databases has `apple` prefix.
So I grant `SELECT` to new user `USER` using multiple command below to.

```
GRANT SELECT ON `apple1` TO 'USER'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON `apple2` TO 'USER'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON `apple3` TO 'USER'@'%';
...
GRANT SELECT ON `apple5001` TO 'USER'@'%';
```

Is there any solution grant to multiple databases has specify prefix using one command like wildcard(`%`) of `LIKE` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GRANT SELECT ON `apple%`.* TO 'USER'@'192.168.0.227';
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is having thousands of databases.  You are likely to be slowing things down by having so many.  (This is an OS problem, since MySQL instantiates each database via a directory.)

Write a Stored Procedure to query against `information_schema` to discover all the databases (using `LIKE`) and generate (using `SELECT ... CONCAT`) the desired `GRANT` statements.  Then manually copy that output into the mysql commandline tool to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

as this came up on a google search, I ended up doing a for loop & piping it into mysql:

`for i in var1 var2 var3 ; do echo "grant all on db_$i.* to user@host;" | mysql ; done`

if using numbers then `for i in 1..1000`
if you have no login details in mycnf file & you have to login to mysql `mysql -u user -password <Password>`
Only issue with the above is your password being in the command history.

Hope this helps anyone looking for a solution.