# Grant permissions to mysql user for future databases

Tags: mysql

I followed this post [Grant on multiple databases. MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204188/grant-on-multiple-databases-mysql) to be able to grant permissions over multiple databases to a mysql user. But I also want to make sure that these permissions persist when a new databases is added to the mysql server. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking because it does not work or are you just asking if that post is correct? If you use backticks with a % sign it should work. You could also use `*.*`

Comment: Global privileges are attached by default to any new database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you grant all database and all table access to any MySQL user while creating then user can access all database/table created after creation of user account.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'host'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'hostname';
```

*.* represents database.table. * indicates all databases and all their tables.